# JQuery Autocomplete a row of data

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

Is there an example that populates more then one form field using JQuery autocomplete? I can do one field bit not sure how to handle multiple columns of data. How do I handle a json string that returns more than one field in an autocomplete operation?

Comment: Please show the code you have so far.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this is what you need, but you can try this:

```js
$(function() {
    var availableTags = [
        "ActionScript",
        "AppleScript",
        "Asp",
        "BASIC",
        "C",
        "C++",
        "Clojure",
        "COBOL",
        "ColdFusion",
        "Erlang",
        "Fortran",
        "Groovy",
        "Haskell",
        "Java",
        "JavaScript",
        "Lisp",
        "Perl",
        "PHP",
        "Python",
        "Ruby",
        "Scala",
        "Scheme"
    ];
    $(".tags").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="ui-widget">
    <label>Tags: </label>
    <input class="tags">
</div>
<div class="ui-widget">
    <label>Tags: </label>
    <input class="tags">
</div>
<div class="ui-widget">
    <label>Tags: </label>
    <input class="tags">
</div>
<div class="ui-widget">
    <label>Tags: </label>
    <input class="tags">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't give a lot of detail in your question, so I can only give very general help...

You can return a list of objects for the autocomplete results. In the select callback you can do whatever additional work needed to fill out your additional form fields from the properties of the selected item's object.

Answer (score 0):

I've got it. Or more accurately I found it. For additional fields in my json string I can redirect them to the appropriate fields like I did for the interpreter-id below.

```
$(function() { 
    $('#ac-name').autocomplete({
      source: "do?action=get-interpreter-names",
        minLength: 2,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $('#ac-name').val(ui.item.label);
            $('#interpreter-id').val(ui.item.value);
            return false; // Prevent the widget from inserting the value.
        },
        focus: function(event, ui) {
            $("#ac-name").val(ui.item.label);
            return false; // Prevent the widget from inserting the value.
        }
    })
});
```